# Can I still right click on an app to move it to the left or right workspace like in 11.04 and before? What about one click switcher?

Tags: 11.10, workspaces

In 11.04(classic edition) and before, one of the best features of Ubuntu was the workspace switcher, none of the other major OS had something like that built natively.  I work with 2 workspaces, one left and the other right.  I will right click apps from left workspace and throw them to the right and vice versa.

In 11.10, I have to:

1. Open workspace from the launcher
2. Drag the app to the other workspace
3. Double click back on my original workspace

What used to take 2 clicks, now takes 1 click, 1 double click and a drag.  Is that the modern way to switch apps between workspaces?

In older Ubuntu, I had the 2 workspace icons at the bottom right corner of my screen.  I can then single click on the left or right workspace for switching.  I'm now doing step 1 and 3 from above to perform that single.

Are there any shortcuts or customization to reduce the number of events I have to go through to perform those simple actions?

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard shortcuts are listed here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces-movewindow.html

Comment: Welcome to AU.  When posting a link that answers a question, it is appreciated if you include the specific answer in the text of the question in addition to the link.  In this case, "`ctrl+alt+shift+arrow` to move window" or something like that.